# SlideShow of Images having Different time durations in django

Tags: jquery, python, html, django, slideshow

Guys I need help in creating an image slide show:

I have two Django template variables . ("ImagesVar" and "ImagesDurationVar")

What I trying to do is I want that "ImagesVar[0]" is displayed for "ImagesDurationVar[0]" time in a slideshow and so on for next image.

MY HTML Code for Django Template is:
=============================================================`

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.slideshow ').cycle({
            fx:     'fade',
            speed:  'fast',
            timeoutFn: function () {
            return parseInt($(".slideshow img").attr('ImagesDurationVar')) ;
            }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    {% for item1, item2 in variable_SR %}
        <div id="content1" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">
            <div class="slideshow">
                {% for ImageVar,ImagesDurationVar in variables %}
                    <img  src={{STATIC_URL}}{{ImageVar}} width={{item1|add:-80}} height={{item2|add:-330}}>
                    <input type="hidden" id="ImagesDurationVar" name="variable" value="{{ ImagesDurationVar}}">
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>  
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</head>
</html>`
```

====================================================================

**Guys I need help for for the Jquery function, its not working.
If you have any help regarding this or any function that will solve this issue, or if above code can be corrected I shall be very thankful to you**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your jquery is doing what you think it's doing. At the moment you're attempting to get the value of an attribute that doesn't exist. You're trying to get the attribute "ImagesDurationValue" from the `<img>` within your div, but it doesn't exist.

Taking from the example [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/timeout2.html)

**EDIT**
Take the script out and put it into a separate file, say, app.js. Then put a list that will contain all your durations.

## app.js

```
var durations = [];

$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.slideshow ').cycle({
      fx:     'fade',
      speed:  'fast',
      timeoutFn: computeTimeout
   });

   function calculateTimeout(currElement, nextElement, opts, isForward) { 
      var index = opts.currSlide; 
      return durations[index]; 
   } 
});
```

Then in your django template:

```
        {% for ImageVar,ImagesDurationVar in variables %}
            <img  src={{STATIC_URL}}{{ImageVar}} width={{item1|add:-80}} height={{item2|add:-330}}>
            <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}/app.js">
            durations.push({{ ImagesDurationVar }});
            </script>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response

I made all the changes but still its the all the images are displayed at once and there is no transitioning

any other suggestion

Comment: I've edited my answer. Try this approach. Also, don't forget to include this line at the bottom of your page as per @sidj9n's suggestion `<script src="{{STATIC_URL}}/<the name of the js file for that plugin>"></script>`

Comment: I make app.js file and follow as instructed but still its stuck in the start and not sliding

Comment: What @sidj9n means is, in order to use the cycle plugin, you must first download their js file from [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/download.html). Once that's downloaded into your `/static/` folder for your django project with the rest of your .js files. Then, at the bottom of your template, you have to add that script file in the same way you did with your app.js file.

Comment: your suggestion with small modifications works fine, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the script at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Do you use this [plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) ? Have you included the script?

Comment: $('#fade').cycle();

I added this at the bottom only

and also I am using App.js script

Answer (score 0):

```
Final solution which work successfully is as follow:

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="60">
    <head>
           <script src={{stati_url}}app.js></script>
           <script src={{stati_url}}jquery_cycle.js></script>
          <title>Front End Running</title>
     </head>
    <body>
        {% for item1, item2 in variable_SR %}
            <div id="content1" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">
                <div class="slidetime">
                <script>
                   var i=0;
                   {% for ImagesDurationVar in variable_1 %}
                        durations[i]={% widthratio ImagesDurationVar 1 1000 %};
                        i++;
                        {% endfor %}
                 </script>
                </div>
                <div class="slideshow">
                    {% for ImageVar in variable_1 %}
                        <img  src={{STATIC_URL}}{{ImageVar}} width={{item1|add:-80}} height={{item2|add:-330}}>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
    </html>
```